# Strange about results of db.currentOp().inprog

Tags: mongodb

I run the command `db.currentOp().inprog`, the results puzzle me.

Why the `ns` is `""`, and the `query` is a null object.

```
    mongos> db.currentOp().inprog[100]
    {
    "opid" : "shard0017:5772491",
    "active" : false,
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "",
    "query" : {

    },
    "client_s" : "10.161.0.93:41833",
    "desc" : "conn592",
    "threadId" : "0x7f81d63b9700",
    "connectionId" : 592,
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "numYields" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {

            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first approach would be to understand the purpose of the method currentOp(). It is defined by Mongo, "Returns a document that contains information on in-progress operations for the database instance." From here you can pass in an *optional* parameter named "operations" The following classifies the input parameter definition.

> Specifies the operations to report on. Can pass either a boolean or a
>   document.Specify true to include operations on idle connections and system operations. Specify a document with query conditions to report only on operations that match the conditions.

Now, given the definition you can specify parameters to target desired operations in progress. Of these, you have indicated both ns and query are null. This is represented as such because you have not specified the namespace (ns) or the document (query) you wish to see the operation of. Essentially, what will be displayed are the values you wish to see the current operation.

> For instance, for a db.collection.find() operation, the query contains
>   the query predicate.

Here is an example of namespace parameter being passed into the currentOp() method.

```
db.currentOp(
   {
     "active" : true,
     "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 3 },
     "ns" : /^db1\./
   }
)
```

Here is a document query that includes a "waitingForLock" condition as well.

```
db.currentOp(
   {
     "waitingForLock" : true,
     $or: [
        { "op" : { "$in" : [ "insert", "update", "remove" ] } },
        { "query.findandmodify": { $exists: true } }
    ]
   }
)
```

For more information check out http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp

Hope this helps!